# What does c do in R?

Tags: r

Consider the code below:

```
k <- c(.5, 1)
```

What does c do here? I think it must be a list or vector. If it is, how can I extend this vector to contain 1024 values?

Comment: What do you want the other values to be?

Comment: I have no idea! But lets assume they must be integers from 1 to 1024.

Comment: The `c()` function will create a vector. Please read [Quick-R: Data types](http://statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) for a better explanation on vectors, matrices, arrays, data frames, lists and factors

Comment: ?c at the terminal will give you the help file for this function. It will also be covered in any introduction to R.

Comment: This previous answer might help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488820/why-use-c-to-define-vector

Comment: Really? I can't believe Dirk was actually able to find a duplicate for that. Next question will be "Why R logo is blue"?

Comment: Along with the `?c` tip, it's helpful to use the mnemonic that the C stands for Combine

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In R, the `c()` function returns a vector (a one dimensional array).

In your example:

```
k <- c(0.5, 1) # k is a vector
k[1] # is 0.5 (remember, R indices start on 1)
k[2] # is 1
```

If you want to create a vector with 1024 entries (assuming 0.5 increments), you have at least two ways to do it:

```
# One way
k <- (1:1024) / 2 # this will be 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, ... , 512
# Another way:
k <- seq(0.5, 512, 0.5)
```

***Also*** you can use `c()` to concatenate two vectors:

```
k <- c(0.5, 1)         # k = 0.5, 1
k <- c(k, 1.5)         # k = 0.5, 1, 1.5
k <- c(k, c(2, 2.5))   # k = 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5
k <- c(k, k)           # k = 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5
```

Please check the help for `c()` and `seq` function (in R: `?c` and `?seq`)

---

**Reference:**

- [Quick-R: Data types](http://statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 8):

The c function in R is used to create a vector with values you provide explicitly. If you want a sequence of values you can use the `:` operator. For example,

```
k <- 1:1024
```

gives you a vector with 1024 values.

---

The built-in help in R is pretty good for questions like this. Just type `?functionName` in your R terminal to get help on any function loaded in your environment.